# Flask's jsonify function inconsistent with flask-marshmallow

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, marshmallow

I am developing an API using flask-RESTful and am having an issue with Flask's jsonify function. I am using flask-marshmallow for JSON serialization. Below is a very simplified code snippet:

```
result = activities_schema.dump(activities)
return jsonify(result)
```

Locally, the endpoint will return json that has keys 'data' and 'errors'; however, when running on a Linux server, this returns a result that contains a list and a dict, without the 'data' and 'errors' keys.

I have determined this inconsistency is caused by Flask's jsonify function by printing out results before they are returned by the API. Both locally and on the server, 'result' equals:

```
MarshalResult(data=[], errors={})
```

However, when I print the response after using Flask's jsonify, I get this locally:

```
('{\n  "data": [], \n  "errors": {}\n}', '\n')
```

while this is printed on the server:

```
('[\n  [], \n  {}\n]', '\n')
```

Anyone know why these don't match?

Comment: Double check that Marshmallow version both in live and local are the same. Since `Marshmallow >= 3`, schemas are always *strict*: [notes on upgrading](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/upgrading.html#schemas-are-always-strict)

Comment: Both are using Marshmallow==2.15, but good to know that change is being made for v3.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I researched some more, and found *one* solution to the problem (I feel a bit silly since the solution is right in the docs), but cannot explain why the original problem happens.

The solution (found [here](https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) is to either use:

```
jsonify(result.data)
```

or:

```
activities_schema.jsonify(result)
```

Either method will return just the data, not the errors.

I still cannot explain why doing it the other way was inconsistent between the server and my local machine, but maybe that's a different question.