# Flask REST API returned json data with extra empty curly brackets at the end

Tags: rest, vue.js, flask, vue-component

So I am making this API to work with my Vue front end, at first everything worked just fine but I don't what happened suddenly the front end can't display the retrieved data properly, I'm using the data on select and it just shows empty options. And when I checked the returned data from the API on postman, it shows something like this :

```
[
  [
    //my data here
  ],
  {}
]
```

As you can see there is an empty curly brackets at the end of the son and I'm suspecting that's the reason the front end can't show the data properly, but if that's not the case then I don't know what is... Please help me...

Here's my front end code :

```
<select v-model="cpuSelect" name="cpu" id="cpu" class="form-control" tabindex="12">
      <option v-for="cpu in cpus" :key="cpu.id">{{ cpu.Name }}</option>
</select>
```

And the script in vue :

```js
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cpus: [],
      cpuSelect: ''
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.load()
  },
  methods: {
      async load(){
        const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/parts/cpu`)
        this.cpus = response.data
      }
  }
}
```

And for the flask model :

```
class cpu(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
Name = db.Column(db.String)
Socket = db.Column(db.String) 

@staticmethod
def get_all_cpu():
    return cpu.query.all()

@staticmethod
def get_cpu(id):
    return cpu.query.get(id)

def __repr(self):
    return '<id {}>'.format(self.id)

class cpuSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
    Name = fields.Str(dump_only=True)
    Socket = fields.Str(dump_only=True)
```

And the flask view :

```
@parts_api.route('/cpu', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_cpu():
  cpu_query_all = cpu.get_all_cpu()
  data = cpu_schema.dump(cpu_query_all, many=True)
  return custom_response(data, 200)

def custom_response(res, status_code):
  """
  Custom Response Function
  """
  return Response(
    mimetype="application/json",
    response=json.dumps(res),
    status=status_code
  )
```

Please help me...

Comment: What is the logic inside the custom_response?

Comment: @EpicChen oh right I forgot to add it

Comment: @EpicChen you can see the custom_response on my flask view snippets now

Comment: Still missing the logic inside cpu_schema.dump. and would your format the code of flask model?

Comment: @EpicChen it's to query the data from my postgresql database and dump it as json, and I don't get what you mean by format the code of flask mode, but if you want to see my flask model I already included it in my question

Comment: Could you provide the result of cpu_schema.dump?

Comment: @EpicChen here you go https://jpst.it/2wEFh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that format of cpu_schema.dump() result is `MarshalResult(data=[], errors={})`, That would be

```py
    @parts_api.route('/cpu', methods=['GET'])
    def get_all_cpu():
      cpu_query_all = cpu.get_all_cpu()
      data = cpu_schema.dump(cpu_query_all, many=True).data
      return custom_response(data, 200)
```

In fact, the empty curly brackets is error information of the `MarshalResult`.

Reference: [Flask's jsonify function inconsistent with flask-marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53269323/flasks-jsonify-function-inconsistent-with-flask-marshmallow)

Comment: Oh I see now, that's explain everything! But what I don't get was when my friend ran the code on the compute with the .data at the end of the syntax he got an error, thanks man

Comment: Tell him to check the reuslt of cpu_schema.dump.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "many" from "dump" call

```
def get_all_cpu():
cpu_query_all = cpu.get_all_cpu()
data = cpu_schema.dump(cpu_query_all)
return custom_response(data, 200)
```